# What are some applications written in Qt that run on both OSX and Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, qt4

I would like to get a feel for how consistent Qt applications can look on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: KOffice, Skype... Or mb you want to see open-source?

Comment: @winch, thanks for those. Any example will be fine. I just want to look at them and learn a little about how they maintained the same UI on different platform.

Comment: Skype on Mac OS X has separate GUI code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [Cross Platform Development](http://qt.nokia.com/qt-in-use/usage/cross-platform-development) page of Qt. For a broader type of applications , see : [Qt-in-use](http://qt.nokia.com/qt-in-use)